# Is concatenate() giving me a neural network with two input nodes?

Tags: python, keras, neural-network

I am using Keras functional API to create neural networks in python.

Here is my code:

```
dayin=Input(shape=(1,))
tempin=Input(shape=(1,))
merge=concatenate([dayin,tempin])
hidden=Dense(3)(merge)
output=Dense(2)(hidden)
```

I know my code creates the following network:

[image]

I wish to make the following feed-forward network:

[image]

> However I am unsure of whether my code is equivalent to  the second diagram. i.e the two diagrams are equivalent.

Any clarification as to how concatenate is working here would be appreciated.

Comment: What makes you think that there is a fundamental difference between the two representations?

Comment: @Dion I suppose in a way, that's what I'm asking. I know my code is creating the second diagram, but I'm wondering if it's equivalent to the first. Ill update my question.

Comment: They are basically the same thing in terms of effective connections and weights.